# Multiple gesture detectors in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using a gesture detector in one of my CustomWidget for detecting drag. Now my CustomWidget is inside a SingleChildScrollView. So when I drag vertically the SingleChildScrollView reacts to that and not the CustomWidget. How can this be achieved?

```
   SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(width: double.infinity),
        VinylSeekbar(),
        SizedBox(height: 12),
        SongControls(title: 'Magic', album: 'Ghost Stories'),
        buildHeading("UP NEXT", 10),
        SongTile(
          title: 'Magic',
          image: 'images/album_art.jpg',
          album: 'Ghost Stories',
        ),
        buildHeading("PREVIOUS", 0),
        SongTile(
          title: 'Magic',
          image: 'images/album_art.jpg',
          album: 'Ghost Stories',
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

In the above sample code the VinylSeekbar is my custom widget where I am using gesture detector for vertical and horizontal drags.

Comment: Could you provide us a code snippet? When I try to recreate this behaviour with a `SingleChildScrollView(child: GestureDetector())` the `onVerticalDragUpdate` still fires without a problem.

Comment: I figured out the solution to the problem in the following article https://www.davidanaya.io/flutter/combine-multiple-gestures.html